# JSP Aircraft Seating Layout

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to develop an experimental Java web application for booking seats via a JSP seating layout. I'm using a Boolean array for the 24 seats and seats are selected by clicking buttons in a form in a JSP page.
**indexRevA.jsp**

[image: indexRevA.jsp using Chrome]

The JSP page is as follows:

**JSP page indexRevA.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="model.manager.SeatManager" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> 
            <form name="chooseSeat" action="BookingServlet" method="GET">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table" class="sortable">
                                            <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat00F" name="submit" id="seat00F" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat03F" name="submit" id="seat03F" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat06F" name="submit" id="seat06F" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat09F" name="submit" id="seat09F" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat12E" name="submit" id="seat12E" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat15E" name="submit" id="seat15E" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat18E" name="submit" id="seat18E" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat21E" name="submit" id="seat21E" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat01F" name="submit" id="seat01F"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat04F" name="submit" id="seat04F"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat07F" name="submit" id="seat07F"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat10F" name="submit" id="seat10F"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat13E" name="submit" id="seat13E"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat16E" name="submit" id="seat16E"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat19E" name="submit" id="seat19E"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat22E" name="submit" id="seat22E"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th><h3></h3></th>
                            <th><h3></h3></th>
                            <th><h3></h3></th>
                            <th><h3></h3></th>
                            <th><h3></h3></th>
                            <th><h3></h3></th>
                            <th><h3></h3></th>
                            <th><h3></h3></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat02F" name="submit" id="seat02F"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat05F" name="submit" id="seat05F"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat08F" name="submit" id="seat08F"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat11F" name="submit" id="seat11F"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat14E" name="submit" id="seat14E"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat17E" name="submit" id="seat17E"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat20E" name="submit" id="seat20E"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="seat23E" name="submit" id="seat23E"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table><br />
                <input type="radio" value="ADULT" name="Passenger" checked="checked"/><p>Adult</p>
                <input type="radio" value="CHILD" name="Passenger" /><p>Child</p>
                <input type="radio" value="INFANT" name="Passenger" /><p>Infant</p>
            </form>

            <h3><%= request.getAttribute("seats")%></h3>
        </div>
                </body>
</html>
```

It submits the choice of Seat to a Servlet, which is shown below:

**Servlet BookingServlet**

```
package controller;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.enums.PassengerEnum;
import model.enums.SeatEnum;
import model.enums.SeatTypeEnum;
import model.manager.SeatManager;

/**
 * Alba Airways application M813-TMA02-ChooseSeat
 *
 * @author james chalmers Open University F6418079
 */
@WebServlet(name = "BookingServlet", urlPatterns = {"/BookingServlet"})
public class BookingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    SeatManager seatManager;

    private int seatNumber;
    private SeatTypeEnum seatType;
    private String msg = "";
    private String url = "";
    private String returnVal;

    /*
     * Creates a new instance of CustomerManager
     */
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        seatManager = new SeatManager();

    }

    public void chooseSeat(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (seatManager.checkNotFullyBooked()) {

            url = "/indexRevA.jsp";
            String passenger = request.getParameter("Passenger");
            boolean isSeatBooked = false;
            if (seatManager.getSeats()[seatNumber] == true) {
                msg = "This seat is already booked. Please choose another seat.";
                request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                url = "/booked.jsp";
            } else {
                seatManager.assignSeat(seatNumber, seatType);
                isSeatBooked = true;
                returnVal = "color:red";
                request.setAttribute("returnVal", returnVal);
                msg = "Your Seat Booking.";
                for (SeatEnum seatEnum : SeatEnum.values()) {
                    if (seatNumber == seatEnum.ordinal()) {
                        if (passenger.equals(PassengerEnum.ADULT.toString())) {
                            double seatCost = SeatEnum.valueOf(seatEnum.toString()).getAdultFare();
                            request.setAttribute("seatCost", seatCost);
                        } else if (passenger.equals(PassengerEnum.CHILD.toString())) {
                            double seatCost = SeatEnum.valueOf(seatEnum.toString()).getChildFare();
                            request.setAttribute("seatCost", seatCost);
                        } else if (passenger.equals(PassengerEnum.INFANT.toString())) {
                            double seatCost = SeatEnum.valueOf(seatEnum.toString()).getInfantFare();
                            request.setAttribute("seatCost", seatCost);
                        }
                        request.setAttribute("passengerType", passenger);
                        request.setAttribute("seatNumber", seatNumber);
                        request.setAttribute("seatType", seatType);
                    }
                    request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                    request.setAttribute("seats", Arrays.toString(seatManager.getSeats()));

                }

                url = "/message.jsp";
            }
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\seats.ser");
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
                oos.writeObject(seatManager.getSeats());
                oos.flush();
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            msg = "The Flight is fully booked. Please choose another Flight.";
            request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
            url = "/booked.jsp";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setAttribute("seats", Arrays.toString(seatManager.getSeats()));
        //request.setAttribute("returnVal", returnVal);
        String submit = request.getParameter("submit");
        if (submit != null && submit.length() > 0) {

            if (submit.equals("seat00F")) {
                seatNumber = 0;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat01F")) {
                seatNumber = 1;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat02F")) {
                seatNumber = 2;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat03F")) {
                seatNumber = 3;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat04F")) {
                seatNumber = 4;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat05F")) {
                seatNumber = 5;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat06F")) {
                seatNumber = 6;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat07F")) {
                seatNumber = 7;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat08F")) {
                seatNumber = 8;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat09F")) {
                seatNumber = 9;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat10F")) {
                seatNumber = 10;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat11F")) {
                seatNumber = 11;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat12E")) {
                seatNumber = 12;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat13E")) {
                seatNumber = 13;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat14E")) {
                seatNumber = 14;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat15E")) {
                seatNumber = 15;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat16E")) {
                seatNumber = 16;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat17E")) {
                seatNumber = 17;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat18E")) {
                seatNumber = 18;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat19E")) {
                seatNumber = 19;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat20E")) {
                seatNumber = 20;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat21E")) {
                seatNumber = 21;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat22E")) {
                seatNumber = 22;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seat23E")) {
                seatNumber = 23;
                seatType = SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY;
                chooseSeat(request, response);
            } else if (submit.equals("seats")) {
                url = "/indexRevA.jsp";
            }
        }
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher
                = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

What I need is a way for the user to tell which seats are booked when he chooses a Seat. Is there a way to change the button colour depending on whether it has been booked or not? I am a novice at JavaScript which is why I've hit this brick wall! My Seat Manager class is shown here:

**SeatManager Class**

```
package model.manager;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import model.enums.SeatTypeEnum;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class SeatManager implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final int NUMBER_OF_SEATS = 24;
    private boolean[] seats;
    private int firstClassCounter;//counter for first class
    private int economyCounter;//counter for economy class
    private boolean isSeatBooked;
    Random randomNumber = new Random();

    public SeatManager() {

        this.seats = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_SEATS];//RESETS Seats TO FALSES
        this.seats = initSeats();

    }

    private boolean[] initSeats() {

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\seats.ser");
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
            in.readObject();
            //String seatsString = (String) in.readObject();

            seats = (boolean[]) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return seats;
    }

    public int getNUMBER_OF_SEATS() {
        return NUMBER_OF_SEATS;
    }

    public boolean[] getSeats() {
        return seats;
    }

    public int getFirstClassCounter() {
        return firstClassCounter;
    }

    public int getEconomyCounter() {
        return economyCounter;
    }

    public boolean isIsSeatBooked() {
        return isSeatBooked;
    }

    public boolean checkNotFullyBooked() {
        for (int i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
            if (seats[i] = true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean areAllSeatsBooked(boolean[] seats) {
        for (boolean b : seats) {
            if (!b) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean[] assignSeat(int seatNumber, SeatTypeEnum seatType) {
        if (seatType == SeatTypeEnum.ECONOMY) {
            economyCounter++;
            if (economyCounter > 12) {
                System.out.println("All the Economy seats have been used up.");
            }

        } else if (seatType == SeatTypeEnum.FIRSTCLASS) {
            firstClassCounter++;
            if (firstClassCounter > 12) {
                System.out.println("All the First Class seats have been used up.");
            }

        }

        seats[seatNumber] = true;
        return seats;
    }
```

**Edit**

**jQuery**
Here's my first stab at AJAX - I want to call a Servlet and receive an array of seat bookings. It nearly works - It wrongly matches seat choices according to DOM index, rather than my row-based seating layout.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "BookingServlet",
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error Occurred");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var receivedData = [];
                    $.each(data.jsonArray, function (index) {
                        $.each(data.jsonArray[index], function (key, value) {
                            var point = [];
                            point.push(key);
                            point.push(value);
                            receivedData.push(point);
                            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = point;
                            $.each(document.getElementsByClassName("btn"), function (index) { 
                                //var x = [Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[index].id)];
                                //document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[index].id;
                                $.each(point[1], function (index, value) {
                                    if (value === true) {
                                        document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[index].style.color = "red";//
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            );
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**AJAXServlet**

```
    package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.manager.SeatManager;
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
@WebServlet(name = "AJAXServlet", urlPatterns = {"/AJAXServlet"})
public class AJAXServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    SeatManager seatManager;

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject member = new JSONObject();

        member.put("arrayData", seatManager.getSeats());
        array.add(member);

        json.put("jsonArray", array);

        try (PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter()) {
            pw.print(json.toString());
        }
    }
```

The next stage is to find a way to select *vacant* Economy seats randomly (ie in the range 12 to 23). I've done everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you want some info from server on your front end:

> What I need is a way for the user to tell which seats are booked when
>   he chooses a Seat.

To make this works you have few techniques:

1. Websocket. This works as bidirectional connection between server and client side, so when other user booked the seat you will get a note on front end. I think this is the best solution here.
2. you can call ajax request from front end but not response immediately. Only when state of your booked seats changed server will send response. This is a kind of hack and rely on max session length
3. Call Ajax every few seconds to know if anything changed. This method is crazy :). It will generate a lot of calls overhead. You should try to avoid this.

After you get data from server it is up to you how to deal with booked seats. You can color them, or make any pop up etc. with javascript code

By the way, the boolean is not the best type for seat array. Think about new class like Seat. It can contain the row number, seat letter mark, emergency entrance sit etc.

Comment: I think I'll try a JavaScript framework and use AJAX with it, rather than use WebSocket (for now). It would be good if someone could suggest a framework.

Comment: AJAX can be called from plain javaScript so pick up any framework, what you like more.

Comment: I've managed to get a JSON array, corresponding to which seats are booked, via AJAX in my JSP page, using the above jQuery script. The next step is to use this data (true/false) to change the colour of the buttons if they are marked 'true'. One thing I've discovered is how useful FireBug is.

Comment: Here's the array: `{"jsonArray":[{"arrayData":[true,true,true,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true]}]}`